# Disconnect users from a networkdrive / close files

Tags: powershell, smb, network-drive

i often have the problem that when im trying to update some data on a networkdrive, other people have that exact file open without working on it, since its taking way to long to tell everyone to close the file i decided to write a tool that automatically disconnects everyone from the networkdrive. I have most of it done but the actual disconnect isnt really working , i am connecting to the server containing the networkdrives via `PSSession` and tried using  `Close-Smbsession` and `Close-Smbfile` but neither of them does work (the file wont actually close ) is there a different command that i dont know of that will actually fully close the file or the connection ?

Comment: Did you mean ```Close-SmbOpenFile```? If so then the file wont actually close on the end users computer, the handle will just be closed in the background.

Comment: Yes, sorry i meant that.

Comment: Provided you have permission this should work. What is the full error message when you try to use a file after closing the open handle?

Comment: Well, im not getting any error messages, its just like nothing happend, i tried it by opening a textfile on the networkdrive and then use a command to show all active connections and their SessionID's , then i use the `Close-SmbOpenFile` command and check if the sessions are gone, and they are. But the file is still open and im able to edit it .

Comment: Ah ok I see. This is expected behaviour, the file will stay open for the end user (even though the file handle has been removed) and a new handle to the file will be created when they attempt to save the file.

Comment: @Otter you should make that an answer. I learned something from you today, and it'd be good for future users to be able to see it as an answer.

Comment: So technically i should be able to edit the file after i closed the session as long as the other users dont save it ?

Comment: Exactly, since the session is closed, its like opening and editing a file as per usual! Depending on the application the user is using, it will treat this change differently. Something like Notepad++ will see that something in the file has changed and prompt the user to reload it, others like normal notepad will just allow the user to save and overwrite without warning them.

Comment: @Jan if this has helped you or you think that this may help someone else then please mark it as the answer as this will make it easier to find for anyone with a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behaviour as `Close-SmbOpenFile` only closes the open file handle and not the application that is holding the handle too.

The file will stay open for the end user (even though the file handle has been removed) and a new handle to the file will be created when they attempt to save the file.

This does mean that while there are no handles to the file (since you just closed them) you can edit it freely.